# Hey, i want to make this little program with canvas and js which detects collisions between circles

Tags: javascript, canvas, collision

i'm learning about canvas and rendering stuff on it with JS, and i'm trying to make a simple collision detection program, which makes the cricles involved in a collision turn a certain color. So far.. it kinda works, which simply means it doesn't work :D i only see random circles turnin green sometimes, not the ones that are actually colliding.

So i wanted to post this here and have you guys take a look at it, and see what you can find. Thx in advance!

I believe the problem is in the 'collisions' function, but i can't quite see what it is.

Btw i'm also open to recomendations on improvements of this code.

this is the html and css

```
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>bubbles</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <p id="fpsIndicator"></p>

        <canvas id="cnv"></canvas>    


    </body>


    <footer>
        <script src="Circle.js"></script>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </footer>

</html>
```

```
#cnv{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    /*background-color: blue;*/
}
```

this is the main JS file and the Circle class

```
let fpsInd = document.getElementById("fpsIndicator");
let canvas = document.getElementById("cnv");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

let frames = 0;
let fps = 0;
let lastCallTime;

let bubbles = 35;
let arrBubbles = [];

const RADIAE = 50;
const COLLISION_COLOR = "green";

adjustCanvas();
window.addEventListener("resize", adjustCanvas);





for(let i = 0; i < bubbles; i++){

    let x = randomInteger(RADIAE, canvas.width-RADIAE);
    let y = randomInteger(RADIAE, canvas.height-RADIAE);

    if(i == 0){
        arrBubbles.push(new Circle(x, y, RADIAE, "blue"));
        continue;
    }

    for(let j = 0; j < arrBubbles.length; j++){

        let d = distance(x, y, arrBubbles[j].x, arrBubbles[j].y);

        if(d <= RADIAE*2){
            x = randomInteger(RADIAE, canvas.width-RADIAE);
            y = randomInteger(RADIAE, canvas.height-RADIAE);
            j = -1;
        }        
    }

    arrBubbles.push(new Circle(x, y, RADIAE, "blue"));
}




loop();
function loop(){
    frames++;
    getFPS();

    if(frames % 3 == 0) 
        fpsInd.innerHTML = "FPS: "+fps;


    ctx.clearRect(0,0,window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);


    arrBubbles.forEach( (item)=> {
       item.draw(ctx); 
       item.move(canvas.width, canvas.height);    
    });

    collisions();

    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}


function collisions(){

    for(let i = 0; i < arrBubbles.length; i++){

        let first = arrBubbles[i];

        for(let p = 0; p < arrBubbles.length; p++){

            let second = arrBubbles[p];

            let d = distance(first.x, first.y, second.x, second.y);

            if(d <= first.radius + second.radius){
                second.color = COLLISION_COLOR;
                first.color = COLLISION_COLOR;
            }
            else {
                second.color = "blue";
                first.color = "blue";
            }
        }
    }

}



function distance(x1, y1, x2, y2){
    let distX = x2-x1;
    let distY = y2-y1;

    return Math.sqrt(distX*distX + distY*distY);
}



function randomInteger(min, max){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max-min+1) + min);
}


function adjustCanvas(){
     canvas.setAttribute("width", window.innerWidth);
     canvas.setAttribute("height", window.innerHeight);
}


function getFPS(){

    let delta;

    if(!lastCallTime){
        lastCallTime = Date.now();
        fps = 0;
        return;
    }

    delta = (Date.now() - lastCallTime) / 1000;
    lastCallTime = Date.now();
    fps = Math.floor(1/delta);
}
```

```
class Circle{

    constructor(x, y, radius, color){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.radius = radius;
        this.color = color;

        this.velocity = {
            X: randomInteger(1, 3),
            Y: randomInteger(1, 3)
        }
    }


    move(canvasW, canvasH){


        if(this.x+1 >= canvasW-this.radius || this.x-1 <= this.radius)
            this.velocity.X = -this.velocity.X;

        if(this.y+1 >= canvasH-this.radius || this.y-1 <= this.radius)
            this.velocity.Y = -this.velocity.Y;


        this.x += this.velocity.X;
        this.y += this.velocity.Y;
    }

    draw(ctx){

        ctx.strokeStyle = this.color;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, 2*Math.PI);
        ctx.stroke();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great job so far. You have all the basics of a game/animation set up correctly. You are right- the only real issue is in the `collisions` function. Look at what's happening in there.

It picks a circle, calling it `first`. Then for every other circle on the screen

- if they intersect, it changes both colors to the collision color
- if they don't intersect, it changes both colors back to the default

Now look over that again, and consider what happens if when the `first` circle checks collision for circles that actually collide with it first. Then the LAST thing to happen in that loop will be checking its collision with the other circles (that don't collide with it) and will change all their colors back to the default.

Basically you need to rethink your logic in how you are creating those two loops. I would suggest for instance, adding a boolean flag (say, `colliding`) that can be checked after the inner loop completes- perhaps even adding it as a property of your `Circle` instances. So if `first` is colliding with something in the inner loop, then set `first.colliding = true`. In your Circle draw() function, you can set the color based on this property.

Luckily, the way these loops were set up, it actually overrode this other bug. You aren't accounting for when the `second` circle is the same object as the `first` circle (it will always have zero distance from itself, so should always turn green... but the bug above always turned it back). You can account for this by adding a check like this inside the inner loop:

`if(first !== second)` or `if(i !== p)` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks alot!! facepalm how could i've missed that hehe, i went for adding the .colliding property to the circles. I've changed the draw and collisions functions, but still no good, now all the circles are permanently drawn with the collision color. This is the new code:

```
function collisions(){


    let p, quitLooping;
    let first, second, d;

    for(let i = 0; i < arrBubbles.length; i++){

        first = arrBubbles[i];
        p = 0;
        quitLooping = false;

        while(p < arrBubbles.length && !quitLooping){

            second = arrBubbles[p];
            d = distance(first.x, first.y, second.x, second.y);            

            if( i !== p)     
                if(d <= first.radius + second.radius){
                    first.colliding = true;
                    quitLooping = true;
                }
                else 
                    first.colliding = false;

            p++;
        }
    }

}

draw(ctx){

        (this.colliding) ? ctx.strokeStyle = COLLISION_COLOR : ctx.strokeStyle = this.color;

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, 2*Math.PI);
        ctx.stroke();

    }
```

Comment: damn... nvm problem solved, i forgot the brackets on that if statement... anyway thanks alot tlong314!!!